# Android - problemas em transmitir Streaming AAC

Tags: java, android, streaming

Estou com um problema no streaming de áudio, ele roda perfeitamente em alguns dispositivos e em outros ele não roda, gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de resolver isto. Ele roda por exemplo em um Galaxy ace 4 neo, mas não roda em um tablet eternum c3 tech.

Depois de algumas pesquisas percebi que o problema é no tipo de streaming. Em MP3 roda perfeitamente porem, em AAC não esta rodando.

O código está desta forma:

```
public class StreamService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "StreamService";
    MediaPlayer mp;
    boolean isPlaying;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Notification n;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    int notifId = 5315;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        // Init the SharedPreferences and Editor
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        editor = prefs.edit();

        // Set up the buffering notification
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        String notifTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        String notifMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.buffering);

        n = new Notification();
        n.icon = R.drawable.iconacusticafm;
        n.tickerText = "Buffering";
        n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, 0);

        n.setLatestEventInfo(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(notifId, n);

        // It's very important that you put the IP/URL of your ShoutCast stream here
        // Otherwise you'll get Webcom Radio
        String url = "StreamingUtilizado/streaming";
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(url);
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "IllegalStateException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
        }   
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        mp.start();
        // Set the isPlaying preference to true
        editor.putBoolean("isPlaying", true);
        editor.commit();

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String notifTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        String notifMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.now_playing);

        n.icon = R.drawable.iconacusticafm;
        n.tickerText = notifMessage;
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, 0);

        n.setLatestEventInfo(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);
        // Change 5315 to some nother number
        notificationManager.notify(notifId, n);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
        editor.putBoolean("isPlaying", false);
        editor.commit();
        notificationManager.cancel(notifId);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É de meu conhecimento que a classe `MediaPlayer` abaixo da versão `android 2.1` possuía pleno suporte a decodificação `AAC`, misteriosamente as versões superiores do android não possuem nativamente opção de decode, mesmo contendo informação de que seja um formato suportado na [lista de codecs](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), aparentemente a classe não executa mais os áudios deste formato, eu fiquei curioso sobre o que aconteceu e tenho algumas considerações, é bem provável que houve algum problema com royalties (google não deve pagar os direitos para utilização deste codec em sua classe), este formato está sujeito a tributação por codificação e decodificação, acredito que os direitos da patente sobre este formato esteja próximo de expirar e assim poderá ser utilizado sem possíveis implicações de cobrança.

Você pode utilizar algum decode `AAC` opensource e assumir os riscos caso sua aplicação tenha um propósito comercial ou possua algum tipo de monetização.

Antes que você me pergunte e o `MP3` porque não temos problema ? bom a patente expirou, se não me engano o prazo máximo para exploração sobre os direitos de uma patente é de 20 anos, antes disso todos os players MP3 assumiam os riscos caso não pagassem licenças.

Você não é o único com esse problema :-(